# How to change property of Eigen vectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, eigenfunctions

I calculated the Eigen values & vectors of two $K$ and $M$ matrices with LAPACK DGGEVX routine. I need to make Eigen vectors orthonormal like this: $\Phi^T M \Phi = I$ .  How can I do that?

Comment: eigenvectors are orthonormal by definition, no?!

Comment: What problem, exactly, did you solve? Depending on the particular problem, you may or may not be able to adjust the eigenvectors in the desired way.

Comment: @Ian $K$ and $M$ are stiffness and mass matrices of an unstable structure (the structure of a building or bridge). Due to instability, I have 6 Eigen values which are very close to zero. Those 6 small Eigen values are corresponding to rigid-body mode shapes of the unstable structure, i.e. 3 translational and 3 rotational rigid-body modes.

Comment: @user3853917 You misunderstand my question; how does one write down the problem expressed in terms of $K$ and $M$? Are you just getting the eigenpairs of $K$? Of $M$? Or is it a mixed problem involving both matrices?

Comment: @Ian I can write down the problem like: `[v,d]=eig(K,M)` in which `v` and `d` are Eigen vectors & values. It's a generalized Eigen problem.

Comment: First, it's somewhat unusual that the eigenvectors are $I$-orthogonal in the first place, because generically $B^{-1} A$ is not symmetric when $B$ and $A$ are symmetric. Second, if $K$ and $M$ are symmetric and $M$ is positive definite then the eigenvectors should automatically be $M$-orthogonal (and hence easily normalized to be $M$-orthonormal). If they aren't already at least $M$-orthogonal (i.e. if $\Phi^T M \Phi$ is not diagonal), then there is nothing you can do to correct it.

Comment: @Ian I feel your comment solved my problem. LAPACK has a routine named DSYGV whose requirement is $K$ and $M$ being symmetric and $M$ being positive definite. Eigen vectors by DSYGV are $M$-orthonormal i.e. $\Phi^T M \Phi = I$. However my matrices are badly-conditioned. Therefore, I'm using another LAPACK routine named DGGEVX which is more stable for badly-conditioned matrices and ignores symmetry of $K$ and $M$. Eigenvectors by DGGEVX are just normalized in a way that maximum of each Eigen vector is 1.0. Good news: as far as I checked, they are $M$-orthogonal i.e. $\Phi^T M \Phi = Diagonal$.

Comment: @Ian Therefore, I feel like I can easily normalize Eigen vectors of DGGEVX to make them $M$-orthonormal ($\Phi^T M \Phi = I$).

Comment: @Ian Is there any procedure for normalization process of going from orthogonal $\Phi^T M \Phi =Diagonal$ to orthonormal $\Phi^T M \Phi = I$ ?

Comment: Sure, just divide each column by the square root of the corresponding diagonal value, since each diagonal value is the square of the $M$-norm of the vector, which you want to be $1$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I guess I will have Eigen vectors containing complex numbers if some diagonal values are negative. Can I ignore the imaginary parts and just take the real parts?

Comment: @user3853917 Is $M$ positive definite? If so then there should be no negative values. Otherwise things are more complicated if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Ian Great! Yes, my $M$ matrix is positive definite.

Comment: @Ian Can you copy your comments to an answer so that I can accept your answer as solution. I wanted to give thumbs-up to your comments, but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a generalized eigenproblem $Kx=\lambda M x$ where $K$ is symmetric and $M$ is positive definite, then the generalized eigenvectors are $M$-orthogonal. This means that if $\Phi$ is the eigenvector matrix then $\Phi^T M \Phi$ is diagonal with positive diagonal entries. It also typically means that they are not Euclidean-orthogonal, that is, that $\Phi^T \Phi$ is not diagonal.

To make the eigenvectors $M$-orthonormal, one can divide each eigenvector by the square root of the corresponding diagonal entry. Then you have $\Phi^T M \Phi = I$.